# Bibliography "?"

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing an article and when i generate the bibliography i can't see it in the article.  The result when I cite an author is : "?".

I don't know how i could fix it, anyone could help me?

Thank you! Cheers!

The preamble is:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\newlength\fwidth
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names} 

blablabla

\section*{References}
\bibliography{bilbiography}
```

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: sorry, i am not expert in the program. I generated the bibliography using a .bib archive. When i compile the article i see a "?" where i input the cite.

Comment: Did the compilation produce a `.bbl` file?

Comment: i am not seeing a .bbl file in the folder where i am working with my article.

Comment: And no `.blg` file? (it is the log file for bibtex/biblatex).

Comment: sorry, i see again the folder and i found a .bbl file

Comment: Then you should compile twice more times  to resolve all references.